# How can I convert aiff to pcm in java?

Tags: java, javasound

I just wanted to convert aiff audio to pcm in java. I would prefer using Java's spi. Ι've found [AiffAudioFileReader](https://github.com/pdudits/soundlibs/blob/master/tritonus-cvs/src/classes/org/tritonus/sampled/file/AiffAudioFileReader.java) on Tritonus library (which works just fine) but there is no ConversionProvider for aiff.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html take a look here in section Converting Audio between Different Data Formats

Comment: @vs97 unfortunately that doesn't work for me as the filesystem has to support converting these specific formats to use this, which it doesn't in this case. From the link you sent: `Of course, the input file must be of a type that the system is capable of reading, and the output file must be of a type that the system is capable of writing.`

Comment: The "filesystem" does not have to support any particular format. Different file types are simply different encodings - the data is bits and bytes. You only have to read in the data, interpret it as AIFF, then encode as PCM.

Comment: @user1258361 so in theory PCM2PCMConverionProvider should work? I'll try that

Comment: @user1258361 It works! Thank you! (you can add it as an answer if you want)

Answer (score 2):

The "filesystem" does not have to support any particular format. Different file types are simply different encodings - the data is bits and bytes. You only have to read in the data, interpret it as AIFF, then encode as PCM.

As the celebrated saying in computer science goes: "Data is symbols **plus interpretation**."